# Reenter the US as a green card holder with a passport nearly to expire

Tags: visas, usa, passports, us-permanent-residents

I live in the US and have a green card. I want to take a 1 week holiday trip to Mexico in May 2021, but my foreign passport will expire in August 2021.

Will I be able to reenter the US with no issues?

In general, the US requires the passport to be valid for at least 6 months, but I don't know if that applies to permanent residents or only visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will I be able to reenter the US with no issues?

Yes.  You can even re-enter the US with an expired passport or no passport at all.  [You only need your green card:](https://www.usa.gov/enter-us)

> Lawful permanent residents of the U.S. need to show a Permanent Resident Card (Green card). A passport is not required.

(This does not apply if you're outside the US for more than one year, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)